# How to serve static files on Openshift from Express?

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

I need an Openshift person to answer this.  Local server working serving files from /static folder on root.  Once ported up to Openshift, "404 not found".  There is something in Openshift that is changing my routes.  I'm using the lines:

```
 const repoDir = env.OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR || __dirname;
 app.use(express.static(repoDir + '/static'));
```

What step am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am user of **OpenShift‎**.

Recently I have came across the similar issue.

Please refer the below to check if it resolves the issue.

**1.** Check if you get the below error.

```
TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'sendFile'
- try Upgrading expressJS version
```

**2.** Use the below approach to serve the static files including js. Working sample

```
<code>
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

  app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/index.html'));
  });
</code>
```

express - version is 4.14.0